# Which opensource license to use to retain commercial rights for myself

Tags: licensing

I am starting an opensource project.
I want to allow the following:
Free for noncommercial use, bins and source mods, like with the GPL, but I would like to retain commercial rights for myself, and provide another license for commercial use for customers who prefer that option.

The number of licensing options seem a bit overwhelming. So my question is:

- Which opensource license should I
  use?
- Which commercial license should    I
  use, if there are any standard ones
  available? Or should I come up with
  my own one here?

Comment: Thanx for that.
David, Marcel. Both answers equally good, Marcel was just first. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem with dual-licensing. GPL is fine for the noncommercial variant, and is widely accepted.

With the commercial one, I do not know of any standard ones. I would recommend you write one, that really suits your needs.

There is Hanselminutes Podcast on licenses here: [Open Source Software Licensing with Jonathan Zuck of ACT Online](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=104). Towards the end they talk about the dual licensing of the MySQL database.

There is also a [transscript of the podcast as PDF](http://s3.amazonaws.com/hanselminutes/hanselminutes_0086_jonathan_zuck.pdf), have a look at the end of the first column on page 7.

Comment: Thanx for that podcast link and the info. Sounds good.

Answer (score 5):

No open source license (as defined by the Open Source Initiative) will forbid commercial use of software.  You can use a version of the GPL to disallow taking your software proprietary; companies could still use it internally, or distribute it for their own purposes, but they couldn't package it up and sell it as normal shrinkwrap software.  Don't use a license like Boost or BSD, as they allow unlimited commercial usage with no restrictions.

You should decide what commercial use you want to allow, and that will depend heavily on the software and what people might want to use it for.

Comment: +1 for pointing out, that commercial USE will be allowed.